# How to format my date with MomentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using *moment.js* to output dates in an app.

The date format is based on the locale (`clientLanguage` variabile).

I tried this one (and many other things):

```
moment(myISODate).locale(clientLanguage).format('ll');
```

but the format I need is different and I can't find a way to have the date in the following formats:

`WED 18 NOV 20:05` and `WED 18 NOV`

Is there any way to do it with moment?

[UPDATE] a very important thing I missed: the locale format should be respected, so if the english way the format date is WED OCT 19, italian should be MER 19 OTT (19 is in another position)

[UPDATE] the guy who downvoted apparently had no solution

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
moment(myISODate).locale(clientLanguage).format('ddd') + " " + moment(myISODate).locale(clientLanguage).format('DD MMM HH:mm')
```

Comment: Problem is: I don't understand if setting the format that way ("dd...") stops locales from displaying the date the right way. Example: WED OCT 19 is ok for english, but for italian it should be MER 19 OTT, where the number is in another place

Comment: Now I know: it "freezes" the date and it stops working the locale way

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
moment.locale(locale);
console.log(locale); //en-US
var now = moment().format("ddd D MMM H:mm");
console.log(now); //Wed 7 Oct 15:06

moment.locale('it');
console.log('it'); //it
var now = moment().format("ddd D MMM H:mm");
console.log(now); //Mer 7 ott 15:06
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfk7k4wc/1/)

For more information about displaying on different formats you can see their [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/).

**UPDATE**: Updated my answer and jsfiddle.

You can check user's browser locale with something like:

```
var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
```

And then set moment.js to use that locale like this:

```
moment.locale(locale);
```

The catch is that you have to include all moment js *locales* files. ([moment-with-locales.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment-with-locales.min.js))

**UPDATE 2**:
Yeah it seems like there is no way to customize it, but it's pretty simple to do it yourself. Just search the source code of moment.js with locales(**not the minified one**) for `'LLLL'` for example, and you will see something like this: `LLLL : 'dddd D MMMM YYYY HH:mm'` change it for every language with your desired output(`"ddd D MMM H:mm"`) and you should be set.

Comment: I need the locale, as I said

Comment: @3000 You should use moment.locale() then.

Comment: Ok, but if I posted is because it doesn't work the way I need   :-)  (or I can't make it work that way)

Comment: It's not ok because for en-us you should have WED OCT 7, not WED 7 OCT

Comment: It is what I was thinking to do as the "final solution", I thought there was a way to avoid this

Answer (score 2):

Try this one,

WED 18 NOV 20:05 - `moment(myISODate).locale(clientLanguage).format('ddd D MMM hh:mm');`

WED 18 NOV - `moment(myISODate).locale(clientLanguage).format('ddd D MMM');`

Comment: Problem is: I don't understand if setting the format that way ("dd...") stops locales from displaying the date the right way. Example: WED OCT 19 is ok for english, but for italian it should be MER 19 OTT, where the number is in another place

Comment: Now I know: it "freezes" the date and doesn't care about locale. Not good for me

Comment: Check out this:  `moment.locale("it"); moment().format('ddd D MMM hh:mm')`

Comment: This is not ok because it's not ok for "en"... The format method freezes the date to the standard you set, it's not aware of multiple locale support